# Lightbox with an ASPX pages

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, lightbox

I'm wondering if you can use a lightbox with aspx pages?
For my project, i'm trying to make some kind of search tool in that lightbox.
On my default page , you have a img link that opens a lightbox (with an aspx page)

In that lightbox, when you click a button (asp button), the page renders like a normal full browser page with the same content. 
The page should stay in that lightbox and rendering the results in a listbox. 
Is this possible? Or is this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One fairly easy solution would be to use the jQuery Thickbox [plugin](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/).  You can use the iFrame solution, which will keep everything tidy.

Another option, you could use any general-lightbox functionality and ajax/post to populate the div in your lightbox.  Note: ajax functionality is also an option with thickbox.

In my opinion, the thickbox solution is the easiest out-of-box solution.  It requires some general jQuery knowledge.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Along the same lines as True North's solution I have done something similar with [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/).

[Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) is also built on the jQuery library and allows pages in iFrames.  It also allows AJAX code, meaning that your search results could be loaded in to the 'popup' without postback!

I hope this helps.